# Can we check member permissions in a channel in another server? (discord.js v12)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

*̶C̶̶a̶̶n̶ ̶w̶̶e̶ ̶c̶̶h̶̶e̶̶c̶̶k̶ ̶i̶̶f̶ ̶t̶̶h̶̶e̶ ̶m̶̶e̶̶m̶̶b̶̶e̶̶r̶ ̶s̶̶e̶̶n̶̶d̶̶i̶̶n̶̶g̶ ̶a̶ ̶m̶̶e̶̶s̶̶s̶̶a̶̶g̶̶e̶ ̶t̶̶o̶ ̶t̶̶h̶̶e̶ ̶B̶̶o̶̶t̶ ̶h̶̶a̶̶s̶ ̶t̶̶h̶̶e̶ ̶n̶̶e̶̶c̶̶e̶̶s̶̶s̶̶a̶̶r̶̶y̶ ̶p̶̶e̶̶r̶̶m̶̶i̶̶s̶̶s̶̶i̶̶o̶̶n̶̶s̶ ̶o̶̶n̶ ̶a̶ ̶c̶̶h̶̶a̶̶n̶̶n̶̶e̶̶l̶ ̶t̶̶h̶̶a̶̶t̶ ̶i̶̶s̶ ̶n̶̶o̶̶t̶ ̶o̶̶n̶ ̶t̶̶h̶̶e̶ ̶c̶̶u̶̶r̶̶r̶̶e̶̶n̶̶t̶ ̶s̶̶e̶̶r̶̶v̶̶e̶̶r̶̶?̶ ̶I̶ ̶w̶̶a̶̶n̶̶t̶ ̶t̶̶o̶ ̶a̶̶l̶̶l̶̶o̶̶w̶ ̶m̶̶e̶̶m̶̶b̶̶e̶̶r̶̶s̶ ̶t̶̶o̶ ̶s̶̶e̶̶n̶̶d̶ ̶c̶̶o̶̶m̶̶m̶̶a̶̶n̶̶d̶̶s̶ ̶o̶̶n̶ ̶o̶̶n̶̶e̶ ̶s̶̶e̶̶r̶̶v̶̶e̶̶r̶ ̶s̶̶o̶ ̶t̶̶h̶̶a̶̶t̶ ̶o̶̶n̶ ̶a̶̶n̶̶o̶̶t̶̶h̶̶e̶̶r̶ ̶s̶̶e̶̶r̶̶v̶̶e̶̶r̶ ̶t̶̶h̶̶e̶̶y̶ ̶w̶̶a̶̶n̶̶t̶ ̶t̶̶o̶ ̶s̶̶e̶̶n̶̶d̶ ̶t̶̶h̶̶e̶ ̶b̶̶o̶̶t̶ ̶w̶̶i̶̶l̶̶l̶ ̶s̶̶e̶̶n̶̶d̶ ̶t̶̶h̶̶e̶ ̶m̶̶e̶̶s̶̶s̶̶a̶̶g̶̶e̶ ̶(̶̶B̶̶o̶̶t̶ ̶i̶̶n̶ ̶2̶ ̶s̶̶e̶̶r̶̶v̶̶e̶̶r̶̶s̶).*

**Update :**
Here is my code - it's worked and very neat.

```
const { MessageFlags } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "say",
    desciption: "say command",

    async run (client, message, args) {
   // />say IDc Text
   let channelID = args[0]
   let msgr
       msgr = args.slice(1).join(" ");
    if (message.member.permissions.has("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) {
        message.delete()
        client.channels.cache.get(channelID).send(msgr);
    } else message.channel.send('BẠN KHÔNG ĐỦ THẨM QUYỀN ĐỂ THỰC HIỆN LỆNH NÀY'); 
} 
}
```

**but I want to check if the person on the server that sent the message who ordered the bot on another server really has the `MANAGE_MESSAGES` permission on the sent server. That is the problem.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. As long as your bot is in both guilds and has permissions for both.

```
// Guild 1
    const guild1 = await client.guilds.fetch(guildID1);

    const guild1Member = await guild1.members.fetch(userID);

// Guild 2
    const guild2 = await client.guilds.fetch(guildID2);

    const guild2Member = await guild1.members.fetch(userID);
```

Do Something with results:

```
    console.log(guild1Member.permissions);

    console.log(guild2Member.permissions);
```

Comment: Thanks Shella : He said " `const guild2Member = await guild1.members.fetch(userID);` needs to be `const guild2Member = await guild2.members.fetch(userID);` "

Answer (score 0):

Yes, completely possible.

E.g.

```js
client.on("message", async (message) => {
   let firstGuildID = await client.guilds.fetch("guild-id").id
   let channelID = await client.channels.cache.get("channel-id").id //get ids of the guild sent from, and channel sent to

   if (message.guild.id <> firstGuildID) return; //assuming command can only be sent from guild 1 to guild 2
   if (message.content === "!test") {
      client.channels.cache.get(channelID).send('test'); //send "test" in the specific channel
   };
});
```

Make sure to read up on `discord.js` docs, for new [fetch](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#fetch) and [get](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#managers-cache) syntax

Comment: (=) === (===) = false

Comment: wrote this out of IDE directly into the website, apologies, did not notice this.

Comment: That's not what I meant (I've updated my question to make it clearer)